# Why do I see no voltage drop in this circuit?

Tags: arduino, diodes, adc, dc-motor, voltage-measurement

What is the voltage drop of a 1N4001 when current is very low?

I am constructing a game that uses an Arduino ADC pin to measure the voltage produced by a person spinning the shaft of a 3V DC motor.  To protect the Arduino from damage if the human player spins the motor shaft in the reverse direction, I placed a 1N4001 diode in between the positive motor terminal and the Arduino ADC pin.  I am surprised to find that there seems to be no voltage drop when the diode is present versus not present.  This is great, but I do not understand why.  I see the same behavior when I use a voltmeter in place of the Arduino.  Is this because the current draw from the Arduino and the Voltmeter are so low?  The [data sheets for the 1N4001](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88503/1n4001.pdf) show a 0.6V drop, but the chart doesn't show the behavior below 0.1A.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftY360.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqb5iz.png)</sup>

Comment: Vf goes to zero as If goes to zero... But I'd be more worried about over-cranking that motor and exceeding the arduino Vcc value.

Comment: The forward voltage for a diode depends in part on how much current it is conducting.  The ADC draws very little current, so the forward voltage is very low.  So low, it is outside of the specifications for your diode.

Comment: Okay, I think that answers it.  Does anyone know of a a graph of 1N4001 behavior at these low currents?  I can't measure these low currents with my voltmeter so I don't even know how much the Arduino is pulling.

Comment: Vfwd of a diode Changes slightly for two reasons: current flow as JRE writes, and also changes inversely to temperature, which my 1N400X data sheets also didn't tell me. Don't rely on a constant Vfwd if you are designing projects which use 1N400X - there's no such rating in spite of the data sheet's insistence of that "0.6V". @Trevor queries Arduino input vulnerability. Don't they have internal diode protection on inputs?  If in doubt, link a 1N4001 diode from the Arduino input to Vcc. In your circuit, capacity anode-cathode won't need considering so a "bog-standard" diode will protect.

Comment: A thought crosses my mind, just reading this for the first time. I think you want to add a capacitor in parallel to the DC motor to help absorb voltage spikes and to accumulate charge, which can then be measured as a voltage. By adding a resistor, also in parallel, so that there is a "bleed rate" too, I think you can then measure the voltage as a function of what you want to measure in the game. Have you tried anything like this?

Comment: The Vf curve at low currents is so steep as to be meaningless.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxSCJ.png